# Proper way to import an iGraph's edgeList

Tags: python, igraph

In a python script, I need to put a igraph graph into a list, then -later on- convert this list back into an igraph graph.

I'm trying this with get_edgelist, like this one

> g = [(3, 4), (6, 7), (7, 8), (4, 10), (5, 11), (0, 13), (1, 13), (7, 17),
>   (13, 17), (16, 17), (12, 18), (0, 19), (16, 20), (17, 20), (2, 21),
>   (7, 21), (10, 22), (6, 24), (17, 24), (8, 26), (18, 26), (5, 27), (26,
>   28), (27, 28), (1, 29), (3, 29), (9, 29), (13, 29), (5, 19), (0, 22),
>   (21, 22), (1, 21), (1, 3), (20, 21), (3, 18), (4, 18), (4, 12), (18,
>   18), (0, 27), (3, 6), (12, 23), (13, 23), (7, 9), (4, 9)]

Then re-importing it as such:

```
from igraph import *
G = Graph.Read_Edgelist(g)
```

Which returns:

> TypeError: string or file handle expected

Any idea what's wrong? Or what's the proper way to do this?

Instead, I wrote a function like this:

```
def edgelist2graph(el):
    g = Graph()
    g.add_vertices(nbr_nodes)
    g.add_edges(el)
    return g
```

Is this an efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `write_edgelist` to save the edge list of your graph into a file - you can then restore it with `Read_Edgelist` later. `get_edgelist` simply gives you a Python list of tuples that represents the edge list of your graph. It cannot be loaded back with `Read_Edgelist` because `Read_Edgelist` works with files or file-like objects.

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but if you simply want to store your graph in some Python object in a serialized form and then load it back later, use Python's `pickle` module instead - this will save not only the edge list but also the directedness, the number of nodes and all the graph, vertex and edge attributes as wel.